# Zone Rates not working oscommerce

Tags: oscommerce

Can someone please help me. Under Modules/Shipping I have set up Zone Rates. I have:
Zone 1 Countries
GB
Zone 1 Shipping Table
2.21:3.20,4.41:5.45,11.1:15.85
Zone 2 Countries
HU
Zone 2 Shipping Table
1.11:5.15,1.66:6.60,2.21:8.05
Zone 3 Countries
TR
Zone 3 Shipping Table
1.11:7.45,1.66:10.15,2.21:12.85

At present I am using Sandbox account. If I set up a fictitious account for United Kingdom sale and associated payment go through. But if I set up a fictitous account for Hungary I get following:

Error Shipping is currently not available for the selected shipping address. Please select or create a new shipping address to use with your purchase.
  I am unable to create a new address inside Hungary.
Delivery Information
New Shipping Address
Please select a state from the States pull down menu.
 I am asked to select a state from the States pull down menu. It's a small empty drop down list where you can't enter anything, and unless this is filled in a new address cannot be created. I have searched and searched on the internet for a solution but just can't find one. Can anybody please help.

Answer (score 0):

This problem it's caused cos the form is not processed, then the country won't be set, so it won't know what zones to display.

If you don't care about hungarian states, just delete them from admin

admin-->zones/taxes-->states
delete hungarian states

---

But if you care about, you could use some contribs like http://addons.oscommerce.com/info/2028